# Sorting Horizontal ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want a list view to sort based on an Object its bounded to

```
    <ListView x:Name="ListView1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentProductsImages}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,2,0" >
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Data, Converter={StaticResource ImageSourceConverter}}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView} },Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource HeightMinusConverter}}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

So the Binded Item CurrentProductsImages has a variable called "DisplayOrder"
I want to order the Listview off this value but can't find a way. Most vertical methods of sorting use a gridview but as mines stacked horizontally i cant get it to work?

I can sort the object prior to binding but i wanted it to be more on the WPF side. any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: Share code behind binding code and data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xaml way of sorting would be to use a collectionviewsource. That has sortdescriptions.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedItems" Source="{Binding UnsortedItems}" >
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
       <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Blaa" />
       <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Blaa2" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

The problem being you can't bind those sortdescriptions.

You could potentially do something with a behaviour or custom frameworkelement. That would allow you to write a bunch of code and kind of make this work in the UI. It'd be more complicated than doing the sorting in the viewmodel though.

I suggest you instead add a collectionview to your viewmodel and handle the sorting there in code. You can define a custom icomparer to use or just clear and add sortdescriptions.

Or sort using Linq if that is better suited to your requirement / skillset.

Examples of sorting (and doing other stuff ) with collections:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26673.wpf-collectionview-tips.aspx

There's a working sample linked.

Esentially, with an observablecollection of People, this is bound using:

```
 public CollectionView PeopleView {get; set;}
```

Set up:

```
 CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
 cvs.Source = People;
 PeopleView = (CollectionView)cvs.View;
```

Sorted:

```
PeopleView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
PeopleView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("OrganizationLevel", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
PeopleView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("LastName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
PeopleView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("FirstName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```